Excel - can't find analys32.xlsx
When I launch Excel I get this message

I've tried repairing Excel and removing and reinstalling the analysis add-in. The problem disappears when I uninstall but returns when I reinstall.  Google provides no hits this file, only on analys32.xll, which is in the directory pointed to be the error message. I've searched my backups and this file doesn't seem to have existed before this problem started.
Excel seems to run fine after dismissing the dialog.
What should I check next?
I'd prefer not to reinstall the whole thing, but that's about all I can think of now.
Office Professional 2016
Windows 10

Check to see which plugins are loading with Excel. Disable these in turn and see if this makes the warning not appear.

I was able to find hundreds of search results on that file. Uninstall the analysis toolpak

Please uncheck and recheck the add-ins‌.  In the Excel add-in interface, first uncheck "Analysis ToolPak" and "Analysis ToolPak-VBA", click OK and restart Excel, then recheck these two options for a check.

@music2myear - analysis is the only add-in I use. As noted in the post, removing that makes the error disappear. Adding it back in makes the error reappear. Analysis ToolPak-VBA is not checked in the first place. But adding it in with Analysis doesn't help.

@Ramhound - are you finding links to analys32.xlsx, or to analys32.xll, which are indeed common but irrelevant.

I am finding links to analys32.xlsx

@Ramhound - what search engine and search term are you using? Typing analys32.xlsx into Google yields two relevant hits. The top one is this post. The second one is a question to Microsoft community support that was posted just yesterday. The unhelpful answer is "reinstall".  All the other hits on the first two pages  are for analys32.xll.

@Llaves - It doesn’t matter which search engine since you said the solution I recommended didn’t work.

Mike, in his answer that doesn't appear to be an answer, still brings up a worthwhile point: Did this just begin recently, and are you allowing the Office installer to check for patches during the install? You mention uninstalling and installing the plugin (I assume); have you uninstalled Office using Off_Scrub (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) and then completed a reinstall? I'd recommend not patching the install until you've confirmed whether the issue is happening again or not.

Edit:
There is a fix from Microsoft: November 19, 2024, update for Excel 2016 (KB4484305), as stated by Joe Salazar in his answer.
The initial workaround below is no longer needed. In case you have already applied it, you should undo it, because the patch from Microsoft does not do it. This can easily be undone by removing and re-enabling the Analytics add-in without having to go into the registry.
Obsolete: the initial workaround before the release of the official patch:
It seems to be a known issue of the security update for Excel 2016: November 12, 2024 (KB5002653).
I was able to apply a workaround by editing the registry entry OPEN in
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options.
By inserting a character at the beginning of the path, it seems to work, at least the error message disappears.
If you are looking for the entry in the registry but cannot find it: it is only there if the Analysis Add-In is enabled (File -> Open -> Add-Ins).
before:
/R "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Library\Analysis\ANALYS32.XLL"

edited:
/R "xC:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Library\Analysis\ANALYS32.XLL"

As usual, please be careful when making changes to the registry: "at your own risk"!
This workaround could work also for issues with other add-ins.
Credits go to Born's Tech and Windows World where I found these tips.

Thank you, it has started to work after the fix.

November 19, 2024, update for Excel 2016 (KB4484305)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/november-19-2024-update-for-excel-2016-kb4484305-c7fdc4c1-5061-c276-254f-5a090a462e4a
Fixes this issue. I downloaded and manually installed it as Windows Update wasn't finding it.
